# Set the TabIndex for a GridView boundfield header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to set the tabindexes for a site and having trouble with the gridview column headings. I can set the tabindex for the form controls (using markup) and the gridview row cells (using C#), but not the gridview column headings. Here's the gridview markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdBCReferrals" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="grdBCReferrals_PageIndexChanging"
            OnSorting="grdBCReferrals_Sorting" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeader" AllowPaging="True"
            AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%">                
    <Columns>            
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedOn" HeaderText="Created On" SortExpression="CreatedOn">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
        </asp:BoundField>            
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I know it's possible because after tabbing through all the gridview cells the column headings receive focus and are tabbable, but that isn't the order I want. I think this is because after the row cells there is no more deliberate tabindexes set and default page tabbing kicks in and sets focus to items that have no tabindex set.

To clarify, the current tabindex is as follows:

Form Controls > GridView Cells > Gridview Headers

I would like it to be:

Form Controls > GridView Headers > GridView Cells

I've been trying to find out how to do this all morning with either markup or code behind but there doesn't seem to be any solutions or forum posts specific to this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this in the end with some help from colleague and I hate it when posts have no update so here goes:

Added a OnRowDataBound trigger for the gridview with the following code:

```
protected void grdBCReferrals_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {            
        int LoopCounter;

        // Variable for starting index. Use this to make sure the tabindexes start at a higher
        // value than any other controls above the gridview. 
        // Header row indexes will be 110, 111, 112...
        // First data row will be 210, 211, 212... 
        // Second data row 310, 311, 312 .... and so on
        int tabIndexStart = 10; 

        for (LoopCounter = 0; LoopCounter < e.Row.Cells.Count; LoopCounter++)
        {                
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                // Check to see if the cell contains any controls
                if (e.Row.Cells[LoopCounter].Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Set the TabIndex. Increment RowIndex by 2 because it starts at -1
                    ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[LoopCounter].Controls[0]).TabIndex = short.Parse((e.Row.RowIndex + 2).ToString() + tabIndexStart++.ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                // Set the TabIndex. Increment RowIndex by 2 because it starts at -1
                e.Row.Cells[LoopCounter].TabIndex = short.Parse((e.Row.RowIndex + 2).ToString() + tabIndexStart++.ToString());
            }                
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else